# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0)'

Tags: rails

I was trying to create a rails application. it created it successfully and at the end it says;
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on
this machine.
 pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this answer on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123761/rubymine-could-not-find-gem-jquery-rails. The Google keyword is your own error message: **Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby'**.